# Что делать, когда равные чилса дают false при сравнении С++

Tags: c++, условия

Столкнулся с довольно неочевидной проблемой. Суть дела в ошибке сравнения двух чисел с плавающей запятой. Если быть точным, то оба числа были long double. Так вот, когда я выводил эти числа на экран, то оба числа отображались как A и A, но вот при сравнении выдавало false, т.е. (A == A) = false. По итогу вопрос: что делать в такой ситуации?

Comment: Из того, что два числа отображаются на экране как одинаковые, совсем не следует, что они равны. А вы еще небось при отображении на экране их еще и урезали сильно. Вопрос "что делать" не ясен. Если числа не равны, то числа не равны. Точка. О каком "что делать" вы ведете речь?

Comment: Сравнивать на полное совпадение double плохая идея. abs(a-b)<0.01 обычно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Числа с плавающей точкой нужно сравнивать `std::abs(a - b) < delta`, где delta требуемая точность. Если возможны случаи inf или nan, обработать их отдельно.